# Adding extra info to each Node -> Taxonomy Term relationship

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

We have a basic site with a pages that have a taxonomy term content type associated with a number of terms.

What we would like to is to add more information to each of the node -> taxonomy relationship.

For example, the details of the author that tagged the term(different authors can tag a term to a node), the date the particular tag was added and so on.

I have looked at the Entity API, the Relation module and various other solutions in between.

From what I can tell, Entity Reference along with the Entity API seems to be the simplest way forward.

While I am not loathe to get my hands dirty and start coding this out, my knowledge of how each of these things fit together is limited.

Can someone point me in the right direction and point out any potential pitfalls along the way with regards to getting this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho, the simpliest way to achieve associations of data with field value **without** coding is to use **[Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)**.

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is
> embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be
> viewed and edited separately too.

You will then be able to set, each time you tag one or more terms, additional informations in other fields of your field collection. Plus, you can have multiple field collections of the same type on your content.

Comment: I had looked at this as well. However in trying to use it, it seems to simply associate an x number of fields to a node. I didn't find a way to use this field to represent an existing entity for example..

Comment: You can also use it to add x number of fields to a field : imagine you add a field collection to your content type, which is "term association". In that field collection, you set a term reference field, and other fields that you need for additional info. Then you'll do your trick, don't you ?

Comment: IF that worked, I would need to select each term manually - right? instead of using the taxonomy widgets? It would not make it easy / possible to add additional information to the relationship automatically created by the taxonomy -> node relationship - it would be creating a new relationship with the additional info - correct?

Comment: Every term relationship widget will be available, with all optinos : several terms at once, etc.

Comment: I've just tried and it *almost* works. The one thing I don't seem to be able to do is let the term selection be multi-select and have a new field collection to be created for each selected term. If the additional fields within the collection can be automatically generated (without user input), is there a way to get a new field collection created for each term from a multi-select?

Comment: I don't see how you could do it _without_ coding a custom ajaxified field collection... :(